# Simple example of a strange problem with jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, toggle

I'm trying to do a simple partial fade effect using toggle to toggle the opacity between two values, when an element is clicked.  But the first click does nothing!

The html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="toggle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="toggler" style="background:grey;width:300px;height:300px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.toggler').click(function(event) {
        $(this).unbind('click');

        $('div.toggler').toggle(function(event) {
            $('div.toggler').css({
                'opacity': 0.5
            });
            alert('0.5');
            return false;
        }, function() {
            $('div.toggler').css({
                'opacity': 0.1
            });
            alert('0.1');
            return false;
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

To elaborate, it does "work", **but** only *after* the first click!  So I need to click twice to begin with to get it working!  I've tried this out in firefox and opera.

Edit: Went with the solution by Marcus Sá and steweb:

```
$('div.toggler').toggle(
    function(event){
        $(this).css({ 'opacity':0.5 });
        alert('0.5');
        return false;
    }, 
    function(){
        $(this).css({ 'opacity':0.1 });
        alert('0.1');
        return false;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, more simple:

```
$('div.toggler').toggle(
    function(event){
        $('div.toggler').css({ 'opacity':0.5 });
        alert('0.5');
        return false;
    }, 
    function(){
        $('div.toggler').css({ 'opacity':0.1 });
        alert('0.1');
        return false;
    }
);
```

See working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sa_vini/vPVfT/)

Comment: inside the functions, you can use $(this) instead of $('div.toggler')

Answer (score 1):

Because you bind to click event once, then unbind, and bind to it again via toggle. What for ? Just use toggle. Here is working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/JKbE2/).

Answer (score 0):

Even easier without having to use toggle:

```
$('div.toggler').css('opacity', .5).click( function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', $(this).css('opacity') == .5 ? .1 : .5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not enough info here, the problem COULD be that your CSS initially sets the opacity to 0.5 to start with, so when you click toggle first, it's already at 0.5 and so it switches from 0.5 to 0.5 and nothing happens.

What I would recommend doing instead is creating 2 css tags, then check which tag is already there and replace it with the other one.

i.e. you can create:

```
.fiftyPercent{ opacity:0.5; }
.tenPercent{ opacity:0.1; }
```

Then in your html start with

```
<div class="toggler fiftyPercent" style="background:grey;width:300px;height:300px;"></div>
```

Then all you have to do in your JS is toggleClass for both the classes on click.

```
$('.toggler').click(function(){
   $('.toggler').toggleClass('fiftyPercent'); 
   $('.toggler').toggleClass('tenPercent');
});
```

That's just my 2 cents.

Comment: This was the obvious way, but I am unable to use a css file in this case.  I thought it was somewhat apparent from the html though (no link to a stylesheet).